# WPF - Using a ResourceDictionary to define a generic style DataTrigger depends on Binding value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model-binding

First of all, I will try to describe the context of what I need.

I have an application, which display a dashboard like this :
[Dashboard-with-KPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcjV9.png)

On each line of those KPIs, when there is a *valueProcessed* I want to see :

> aTitle : valueToProcess/valueProcessed [%]

But when there isn't any *valueProcessed* I need this :

> aTitle : 0 [n/a]

In order to achieve it, I used a DataTrigger like this :

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NbLocationToInstall}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard}" Text="{Binding NbLocationInstalled}"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard_NoSpace}" Text="/" />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard}" Text="{Binding NbLocationToInstall}"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard}" Text="{Binding PrLocationInstalled, StringFormat={}[{0:0.##} %]}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NbLocationToInstall}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard}" Text="{Binding NbLocationToInstall}"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard}" Text="[n/a]" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Displaying a StackPanel depends on a binding value called *NbLocationToInstall*.

This solution works but, I have a lot of rows of KPI to display, and I don't want to repeat this block (=> ***n*** rows mean ***n*** block like this, just binding values will change).

So I have decided to create a dictionary, there I set my style :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Dictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <Style x:Key="ValidTrigger" TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NbLocationToInstall}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="InvalidTrigger" TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NbLocationToInstall}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And now, I can use it like this :

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ValidTrigger}">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard}" Text="{Binding NbLocationInstalled}"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard_NoSpace}" Text="/" />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard}" Text="{Binding NbLocationToInstall}"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard}" Text="{Binding PrLocationInstalled, StringFormat={}[{0:0.##} %]}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource InvalidTrigger}">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard}" Text="{Binding NbLocationToInstall}"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard}" Text="[n/a]" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

But how can I change the binding value of DataTrigger style **ValidTrigger** ?
This is valid here for this example, given in the context, but for other rows, I want to pass another binding variable. And there, it is **NbLocationToInstall**, defined in ResourceDictionary.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Represent each row with a detail viewmodel class. Give your main viewmodel an ObservableCollection with all the "row" class instances in it. Display them in an ItemsControl with a DataTemplate which does whatever you need it to do. Don't reinvent the wheel, this is easy stuff if you use WPF as directed.

Comment: Your suggestion seems to be good, however when I will look at my view, there aren't any KPI and without running the application I can't see what it is expected. So, do you think this RUNTIME answer is the best one ? Because at first I considered it as a skeleton.

Comment: My suggestion is the way WPF works best and is most easily used. The WYSIWYG designer view is worthless. I never even look at it. I do agree it's a little bit inconvenient to have to run to see what template changes look like. You could look into providing "mock" data to see your templates in the designer, though it will never look like it would at runtime anyway.

Comment: Ok thank you for advice, I'm doing it. I will post back my work asap.

Comment: I post a reply with the implementation. It works but I would appreciate if you can have a look to confirm it is the best way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1):

According to the suggestion, I made a review of my code.

First of all, this is the XAML code definition :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Dictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <Style x:Key="ValidTrigger" TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ValueToProcess}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="InvalidTrigger" TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ValueToProcess}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<!-- Detailed Information -->
<GroupBox Header="{x:Static lang:Resource.DetailedInformation}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource GroupBox_Default_Dashboard}">

    <StackPanel>
        <UniformGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Columns="2">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default}" HorizontalAlignment="left" Text="{x:Static lang:Resource.DeploymentTime}" />
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:00} h {1:00;00} min">
                        <Binding Path="Time.Hours" />
                        <Binding Path="Time.Minutes" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </UniformGrid>

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding KPIs}" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.45" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Label}"/>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ValidTrigger}">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard}" Text="{Binding ValueProcessed}"/>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard_NoSpace}" Text="/" />
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard}" Text="{Binding ValueToProcess}"/>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard}" Text="{Binding ValueProcessed, StringFormat={}[{0:0.##} %]}" />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource InvalidTrigger}">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard}" Text="{Binding ValueToProcess}"/>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_Default_Dashboard}" Text="[n/a]" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

This is the KPI model :

```
/// <summary>
/// provide a container to display a simple KPI
/// </summary>
public class KPI
{
    // props
    public string Label             { get; private set; }
    public double ValueToProcess    { get; private set; }
    public double ValueProcessed    { get; private set; }
    public double Percentage        { get; private set; }

    // default ctor
    public KPI(string label, double valueToProcess, double valueProcessed)
    {
        this.Label          = label;
        this.ValueToProcess = valueToProcess;
        this.ValueProcessed = valueProcessed;
        this.Percentage     = (valueToProcess == 0) ? Double.NaN 
                                                    : ValueProcessed / ValueToProcess * 100;
    }
}
```

This is the declaration :

```
ObservableCollection<KPI> _KPIs;
public ObservableCollection<KPI> KPIs
{
    get { return _KPIs; }
    set
    {
        _KPIs = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("KPIs");
    }
}
```

This is the definition :

```
KPIs = new ObservableCollection<KPI>()
{
    { new KPI(Lang.Resource.Label1, 5, 0) },
    { new KPI(Lang.Resource.Label2, 0, 0) },
    { new KPI(Lang.Resource.Label3, 0, 0) }
};
```

And It works perfectly.

I hope it could help anyone else.

Comment: I have edited KPI model, it is better to use a double as a type representation for percentage. And if it is not possible to calculate it, just set it to NaN.